# Service Fabric Remote call after upgrading packages

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I've just upgraded my SF packages to the latest version (6.3.162). Calls to my services which were working fine yesterday are now all crashing with the following error:

> Field not found: 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.ServiceTrace.Source'.

Stack trace:

> at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Builder.InterfaceDetailsStore.UpdateKnownTypes(Int32 interfaceId, String interfaceName, InterfaceDetails knownTypes)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Builder.InterfaceDetailsStore.UpdateKnownTypesDetails(IEnumerable`1 interfaceDescriptions)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Builder.ServiceCodeBuilder.BuildProxyGenerator(Type interfaceType)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.CodeBuilder.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ICodeBuilder.GetOrBuildProxyGenerator(Type interfaceType)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Builder.ServiceCodeBuilder.GetOrCreateProxyGenerator(Type serviceInterfaceType)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Client.ServiceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy[TServiceInterface](Uri serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey, TargetReplicaSelector targetReplicaSelector, String listenerName)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Client.ServiceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy[TServiceInterface](Uri serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey, TargetReplicaSelector targetReplicaSelector, String listenerName)
>      at Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade.Controllers.PaymentController.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

Here is one call (one of my attempts to fix it was to try to make the calls with the v2 remoting stack, so I'm not sure this works):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerId(string mail)
    {
        return await TelemetryManager.ServiceRemotingDependencyCallAsync<IActionResult>(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //var proxy = ServiceProxy
                    //    .Create<IPayment>(_paymentServiceUri);

                    var proxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory(c => 
                        new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory());

                    var proxy = proxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IPayment>(_paymentServiceUri);

                    var customerId = await proxy
                        .GetStripeCustomerIdAsync(mail)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

                    return Ok(customerId);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest(e.InnerException);
                }

            },
            dependencyType: DependencyType.StatelessService,
            dependencyName: DependencyName.PaymentService,
            target: _paymentServiceUri.ToString())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Service called:

```
manifest : 
<Endpoints>
  <!--<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />-->
  <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpointV2" />  
</Endpoints>
```

```
payment.cs contains
[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListenerVersion = RemotingListenerVersion.V2, RemotingClientVersion = RemotingClientVersion.V2)]

protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    //yield return new ServiceInstanceListener(this.CreateServiceRemotingListener);
    //return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
    yield return new ServiceInstanceListener(c => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(c, this));
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: local cluster or azure cluster? Is the cluster upgraded as well? If it is the local cluster, did you install the latest tooling as well?

Comment: it's local atm, I installed the latest SF SDK and started to get this : Field not found: 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.ServiceTrace.Source'., stacktrace was different as I started with remoting V1. the call to the façade (stateless asp.net core) works, then when I call the service I got the error. A good old unplanned waste of time ...

Answer (score 0):

Xav

Could you check your other SF nuget packages versions . Are all the same as 6.3.162?
And which SF runtime version you are using?

Comment: yes all services share the same versions of every packages Microsoft.ServiceFabric 6.3.162 and Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.2.162 (other SF packages are up to date as well); Service Fabric SDK 3.2.162 installed on my machine

Comment: rollbacked to previous version, everything's working fine again … something's fishy with those new packages ...

Comment: We have seen this issue when there is a mismatch between SF nuget packages . I would say install SDK 3.2.162, uninstall old nuget package and then install new nuget packages. Don't use "Update" option.